# ASP.NET VB Color single Row in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to color single Rows when there empty in a Gridview, but it changes the color from every Row empty and not.

```html
Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

... SQL Connection Stuff

Using dt As New DataTable()
sda.Fill(dt)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()

Dim Menge As Integer = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

For i = 0 To Menge
  For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    If GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text = "" Then
      GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
  End If
  Next
Next

End Sub
```

Can someone Help me?

Comment: You should run your for loop in the GridView_RowDataBound event.

Comment: Do you want to color the whole row or just the cell with  index 4?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code in your `Default_Load` event, but this will only color rows when page loads. Ideally, you should hook up the `RowDataBound` event with your grid view.

**Code if using Default_Load event**

```
Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

... SQL Connection Stuff

Using dt As New DataTable()
sda.Fill(dt)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()

'color rows based on some condition
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    If row.Cells(4).Text = "" Then
        row.Cells(4).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Code if using RowDataBound event**

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.Cells(4).Text = "" Then
            e.Row.Cells(4).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your Code, but still all Cells 4 will be Colored

Comment: are all the cells that are colored have empty text?

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your grid view after you use my code? i am suspecting that `Cells(4)` has empty text for all the rows that you say are colored.

Comment: Try with the code that I just changed. Note that only the cell with index of 4 would be colored with red.

Comment: Why are putting this in RowDataBound. I gave code for Default_Load event. Please move that code to Default_Load and remove it from RowDataBound.

Comment: I have added two code snippets, and you need to use only one of them. The second code snippet is the best approach in your situation.